# Why was an answer not awarded a bounty?

Tags: support, bounty

I am not sure about the precise date when a bounty started as to the bounty rules,

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full
>   amount, if the answer is also accepted).

Though, why did user "Community" not award half the bounty to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42194882/) at *[Preload mp3 file in queue to avoid any delay in playing the next file in queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42049639/preload-mp3-file-in-queue-to-avoid-any-delay-in-playing-the-next-file-in-queue/)*?

Comment: The bounty was started after that answer was posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rule #1 of automatically awarding bounties ([FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95040/164356)):

> The answer must be given after the bounty was started.

The bounty was started on Feb 13 at 9:00. The answer was posted at 0:23, 8 hours earlier.

So it wasn't eligible.

Comment: Does this mean someone can "snipe" unclaimed bounties by literally posting anything as an answer if there are no other answers meeting the criteria?

Comment: @code11 yes, if it gets a score of +2 (which I think isn't the case for last-minute answers)

Comment: Or delete and re-create the answer after the bounty is started

Comment: @Floern Does the same apply for bounty at this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41191131/are-there-differences-between-thenfunctionreference-and-thenfunctionvalue?

Comment: @guest271314 neither of the two answers posted during the bounty period got a score of 2, which is required to have the bounty auto-awarded.

Comment: @Floern That is not accurate. The highest voted Answer received more than 2 votes during the active bounty.

Comment: @guest271314 as far as I can see the bounty period was from May 20th to 28th and I see only two answers posted during that period, both having a score of 0. The other two are too old for the bounty.

Comment: That is was meant by does the same apply? The bounty was created to award an existing Answer.  Was unfortunately occupied with an account suspension and was unable to award the bounty. Though the highest voted Answer did receive more than 2 votes during the active bounty period. Could not reconcile the rules for the case where more than 2 votes were received, though Answer was posted before bounty began.

Comment: @guest271314 then yes, if you want to award it to an existing answer you have to award it manually. Auto-awarding won't work in that case because of that rule.